# how to display these results from tweepy in an array format suitable to jquery

Tags: html, jquery, django, pandas, dataframe

class TweetAnalyzer():
""""
Class for tweet analysis
"""
def tweet_to_data_frame(self, tweets):
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets ], columns=['tweets'])

```
    df['id']= np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
    df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
    df['date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets])
    df['source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in tweets])
    df['likes'] = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets])
    df['retweets'] = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets])
    df['in_reply_to_screen_name'] = np.array([tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name for tweet in tweets])
    df['in_reply_to_status_id'] = np.array([tweet.in_reply_to_status_id for tweet in tweets])
    df['in_reply_to_user_id'] = np.array([tweet.in_reply_to_user_id for tweet in tweets])

    #the loops are essential in the data presentation ('for tweet in tweets')
    print(json.dumps(df, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
    return json.dumps(df, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

Comment: the result comes in a tablular form because of pandas and jquery is unable to read it

Comment: and i want the results in a regular array(json) format that i can be able to loop through and display the result using datatable in jquery